# FileNameController cannot find the requested view "create" in Yii 1

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii

I have upload a new form in an existing webapp which is live (Linux server). But I am not able to set the route properly and get error.

Files : 
1. view/newform/(create,index,view,_view,_form).php

2. controllers/NewFormController.php
3. models/NewForm.php

main.php :

```
'urlManager' => array(
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'urlFormat' => 'path',
            'rules' => array(
            '/' => 'site/index',
            'newform' => 'newform/create', /*This rule is for new form */

   **********************************
```

Link I use to access the wbepage online :

```
websitename.com/newform/create or create.php (I get 404 not found)
websitename.com/NewForm/create or create.php (NewFormController cannot find the requested view "create" error )
```

I can view it properly on localhost(windows) => 
localhost/public_html/index.php?r=newform/create

Questions : 
What link should I use to view it online ?
How to get correct Route to the form I created ?

Edited : 
I can view the index page after adding the path (/newform/index) in actionIndex(). controller

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('NewForm');
        $this->render('/newform/index',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        ));
    }
```

Here is the create function :
When I use this the error I get  : cannot find the requested view "_form"

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new NewForm;

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['NewForm']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['NewForm'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('/newform/create',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }
```

Comment: You are using Yii1 or Yii2 ?

Comment: I am using Yii 1

Comment: In my opinion, you should use
    $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found It :P

```
$this->render('/newform/_form',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
```

in crontroller